# How should a function with a const ** argument be defined to minimize the need for unnecessary const_casts by callers?

Tags: c++, constants

The const in an argument declaration represents that the function being declared will not change the const value. When the function argument is a handle (**) to the const object, a caller will need to perform a const_cast if the constness of the argument does not match the constness of the function's declared argument type... even though (as the programmer of the function knows) it does not matter. How should the function be declared to minimize the need for const-casting of the arguments by callers?

The defining code:

```
void Func(const Foo**);

main()
{
  Foo* fooPtr;
  Func(&fooPtr);
}
```

The compiler (Visual Studio 2012) yields:

```
> error C2664: 'Func' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Foo**' to 'const Foo**'
> Conversion loses qualifiers
```

But the following works:

```
main()
{
  Foo* fooPtr;
  Func(const_cast<const Foo**>(&fooPtr));
}
```

On the other hand, changing the declaration of Func() to

```
void Func(Foo**);
```

requires const_cast when called with a const argument.

When the function changes NEITHER the object NOR the pointer to the argument, Func() can be declared as

```
void Func(const Foo*const*);
```

However, when the function might change the pointer value (while still leaving the object itself unchanged) this is not appropriate.

Comment: Foo const** is a pointer to a pointer to a Foo object. You describe it as a handle to an object, but it is more like a handle to a handle to an object. In standard terms, a std::shared_ptr<Foo const> is something like a handle to an object, and can be passed as a const reference to a function void f(std::shared_ptr<Foo const> const&). Why do need a pointer to a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it is the case that Func(&fooPtr) indeed modifies fooPtr while leaving *fooPtr unchanged, there are circumstances in which it is safe to declare two versions of Func(), one defined in terms of the other:

```
void Func(const Foo**);
void Func(Foo** fooHndl)
{
  Func(const_cast<const Foo**>(fooHndl));
}
```

This allows Func() to be called with a handle (**) to either a const or non-const object.

This function should only be declared in this way when it is known that any reassignment of *fooHndl would be to a non-const Foo*, i.e. of the form

```
Foo* fooPtr;
*fooHndl = fooPtr; // fooPtr is non-const
```

This condition is absolutely necessary, since if the function violates this condition, then if the caller calls the function with a non-const argument and subsequently modifies the object, he would be inadvertently modifying the const object.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, int** is incompatible with const int** because you could otherwise do:

```
const int some_ints[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

void func (const int ** ptr)
{
  *ptr = some_ints;
}


void bad (void)
{
  int *ptr;

  func (&ptr);

  *ptr = 99;   // illegal because ptr now points to some_ints, which is const
}
```

but if you say "func (const int * const * ptr)" you can't assigned ptr within func, hence no problem.

In "When the function argument is a handle (**)" you use the term "handle" to mean "pointer to pointer [to Foo]".

You therefore have three things:

1. A pointer (to a pointer to Foo).
2. A pointer to Foo.
3. A Foo.

and hence three things that can be constant, giving eight options:

```
void func (const Foo * const * const ptr)  // 1, 2, 3 are constant

void func (Foo * const * const ptr)        // 1, 2 are constant

void func (const Foo ** const ptr)         // 1, 3 are constant

void func (const Foo * const * ptr)        // 2, 3 are constant

void func (Foo ** const ptr)               // 1 is constant

void func (Foo * const * ptr)              // 2 is constant

void func (const Foo ** ptr)               // 3 is constant

void func (Foo ** ptr)                     // Nothing is constant
```

So:

1. Declare your function appropriately, based on what it needs to change (i.e. 1, 2 and/or 3). Given that:
2. You shouldn't need any const_casts, unless you're promising to the compiler that you know best.

In general you'll find that your entire program needs to be strict about constness to avoid compiler warnings or casts. This is a pain when you use third-party libraries that aren't careful with constness in their public API.

(All of the above is strictly speaking C rather than C++; C++ also has const member functions, which mean something else entirely.)